# How to add an AWS-Lambda-based trigger on S3-Bucket with CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk, aws-cli

I'm curious if we could create a trigger on a AWS S3 Bucket programmatically?

Given is a S3-Bucket and a AWS Lambda function.
The AWS Lambda function was created per CLI and can be updated/recreated at any time with CLI-based commands.

```
aws lambda create-function \
--region us-east-1 \
--function-name encodeVideo \
--zip-file fileb:///tmp/encode_video.zip \
--role $LAMBDA_ROLE_ARN \
--handler encode_video.handler \
--runtime nodejs6.10 \
--timeout 10 \
--memory-size 1024


aws lambda add-permission \
--function-name encodeVideo \
--region us-east-1 \
--statement-id some-unique-id \
--action "lambda:InvokeFunction" \
--principal s3.amazonaws.com \
--source-arn arn:aws:s3:::**** \
--source-account ***********
```

Now i want to configure a S3-bucket that it will invoke the Lambda function automatically on every new object that was created.

For now i did this in AWS Console in web browser as one can see in the screenshot. But i want to be able to setup the whole scenario with CLI-commands. How can i do this?

I've figured out that it needs something like:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration --region us-east-1 \
--bucket **** \
--notification-configuration file://encodeVideoConfiguration.json
```

But i couldn't figure out what the content of *encodeVideoConfiguration.json* should be?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The document structure of `--notification-configuration` is described in detail at at [AWS CLI docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-notification-configuration.html) for the same call:

```
{
  "TopicConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "string",
      "TopicArn": "string",
      "Events": ["s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject"|"s3:ObjectCreated:*"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Put"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Post"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Copy"|"s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:*"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated", ...],
      "Filter": {
        "Key": {
          "FilterRules": [
            {
              "Name": "prefix"|"suffix",
              "Value": "string"
            }
            ...
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  ],
  "QueueConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "string",
      "QueueArn": "string",
      "Events": ["s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject"|"s3:ObjectCreated:*"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Put"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Post"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Copy"|"s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:*"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated", ...],
      "Filter": {
        "Key": {
          "FilterRules": [
            {
              "Name": "prefix"|"suffix",
              "Value": "string"
            }
            ...
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  ],
  "LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "string",
      "LambdaFunctionArn": "string",
      "Events": ["s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject"|"s3:ObjectCreated:*"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Put"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Post"|"s3:ObjectCreated:Copy"|"s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:*"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete"|"s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated", ...],
      "Filter": {
        "Key": {
          "FilterRules": [
            {
              "Name": "prefix"|"suffix",
              "Value": "string"
            }
            ...
          ]
        }
      }
    }
    ...
  ]
}
```

For your case, you'd just provide the `LambdaFunctionConfigurations` field of JSON structure.

Answer (score 2):

This is the JSON configuration you want to create.

```
{
"LambdaFunctionConfigurations": [
    {
      "Id": "s3eventtriggerslambda",
      "LambdaFunctionArn": "theactualarn",
      "Events": ["s3:ObjectCreated:*"],
      "Filter": {
        "Key": {
          "FilterRules": [
            {
              "Name": "suffix",
              "Value": "thesuffix"
            },
            {
              "Name": "prefix",
              "Value": "theprefix"
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Copy the above json to a file named "s3triggerlambdaconfig.json"
From aws cli:

```
aws s3api put-bucket-notification-configuration \
--bucket bucketname \
--notification-configuration file://s3triggerlambdaconfig.json
```

Example lambda arn will be like this - arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:550060223145:function:lambda-function-test

Answer (score 0):

Were you ever able to get this to work? I am looking for something very similar and so far have not been able to get it to work.

I want to trigger Lambda on s3 object add/delete and want to do it from the cli with the source bucket passed as an argument.